# Deploy data base with setup project

Tags: sql, deployment

Hi can some body help me please?
I'd like to know how to add a sql script to a setup project, so that after the instalition the data base is implémented?
I mean that the setup project implement the data base that I add it to the setup project with the sql script
I'm using c#, wpf, SQL SERVER2008, VisualSutdio 2008
thank's

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with SQL CLR projects in visual studio that use \Scripts\Pre-Deployment and \Scripts\Post-Deployment folders to do exactly what you describe. In your case, try adding a database project type to your solutions. You should should be able to add the scripts needed to create the database and add objects. Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833410.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Setting up projects bundle and distribute applications and databases. This deployment technique builds a development environment setup project to add database files, define connection strings, describe installation, and build an installer. Guided installation ensures database setup and application connectivity. Users learn the program from documentation and testing. Software setup projects streamline application and database deployment.

Consider updates and maintenance when constructing a database. New installers may be needed for app updates or bug fixes to bring features and improvements. Successful database deployment improves user experience, application reliability, and functionality, making it crucial to software development and distribution.